# ANDROID - Clear DB/Cache while changing the language in android Phone/Tablet

Tags: android

I have developed a app which supports FRENCH AND ENGLISH language. App is getting data from API.

I am using following code to store LAST UPDATED TIME for synch.

```
  public static long getLastUpdatedTime(Context ctx) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
    return sharedPref.getLong(PREF_LAST_UPDATED_TIME, 0);
}

public static void updateLastUpdatedTime(Context ctx, Long time) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sharedPref.edit();
    ed.putLong(PREF_LAST_UPDATED_TIME, time);
    ed.commit();
}
```

App is working is fine but if user changes the LANGUAGE in phone/tablet then above stored value is not getting cleared. I want to clear cache when user switch from one language to other.

Is it possible?

I want to do this because I am appending last updated server time to URL while synching.

```
timefromcache = getLastUpdatedTime(context);
synchurl = www.xyz.com/data/customers/?time=timefromcache
```

I want to get language specific data from server while changing the mobile/tablet language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can simply check language of the device by:

```
Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
```

This should return for example 'DE' or 'PL'.
Then can save this in `SharedPreferences`.
Each time your app starts (or maybe even on `onResume()` in all your activites) you should check if current device language equals this one from `SharedPreferences`. If not you should clear your cache/database/whatever.